# Read NTAG213 protected with an android device

Tags: android, nfc, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm designing an Android app to read protected ntag213 tags. I'm tag's owner.
I've written before  the pwd and pack  with a reader correctly.

I'm able to read it with the Samsung Young 2, android version 4.4.2.

When I try to read them with a Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo Android 4.4, I have an exception with the same code sending PWD command and reading the answer.

When I use some apps to read this tag, as TagInfo or NFCTools with Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo the tag is recognized as ntag203. With Samsung Young Galaxy 2 I don't have this problem, the app recognizes it ok.
What's happening? What's wrong?

I tested with OnePlus One mobile and doesn't work, I have an read exception too.

Thanks in advanced.

Jaime

---

Here is the Exception message and the stack:

```
 java.io.IOException: Transceive failed
```

and the stacktrace:

```
 {java.lang.StackTraceElement[18]@830038119016} 
0 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038119112} "android.nfc.TransceiveResult.getResponseOrThrow(TransceiveResult.java:52)"
1 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038119440} "android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.transceive(BasicTagTechnology.java:151)"
2 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038119776} "android.nfc.tech.NfcA.transceive(NfcA.java:120)"
3 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038120048} "com.appname.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:259)"
4 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038120360} "android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1167)"
5 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038061384} "android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2455)"
6 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038061704} "android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2468)"
7 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038062024} "android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2477)"
8 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038062344} "android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:169)"
9 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038062608} "android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348)"
10 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038062928} "android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)"
11 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038063216} "android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)"
12 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038063480} "android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)"
13 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038063776} "java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)"
14 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038064072} "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)"
15 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038064352} "com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)"
16 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830038064696} "com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)"
17 = {java.lang.StackTraceElement@830046325096} "dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)"
```

And the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "appname MainActivity";
byte[] pwd_NTAG213 = new byte[]{(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01};
byte[] pack_NTAG213 = new byte[]{(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x01};

private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
byte[] UID = new byte[8];
byte[][] Buf = new byte[3][16];
byte [] DeviceUID =new byte[16];


public static MainActivity myActivity;
static boolean isActive = false;
static boolean scanTag =false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(layout.activity_main);


    myActivity =this;
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
        // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
        Toast.makeText(this, "No NFC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    if (!mNfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        askUserToOpenNFC();
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    isActive = true;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    isActive = false;
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    WriteModeOn();
}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    WriteModeOff();
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi") private void WriteModeOn(){
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    String[][] techList = new String[1][1];
    techList[0][0] = "android.nfc.tech.NfcA";

    IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[2];
    filters[0] = new IntentFilter();
    filters[0].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    filters[0].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    filters[1] = new IntentFilter();
    filters[1].addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    filters[1].addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    if (mNfcAdapter != null) {
        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi") private void WriteModeOff(){
    mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi") protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    NfcA nfca;
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

    String device_unique_id =     Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(id.lytLayout));
    TextView txtMsg = (TextView)layout.findViewById(id.txtMensaje);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(layout);

    if (!scanTag)
        return ;
    scanTag = false;

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)){
        nfca = NfcA.get(tag);
        UID = tag.getId();
        try {
            nfca.connect();
            if (!nfca.isConnected()) {
                return;
            }
            //··················································································PassWord +PACK
            Log.i(TAG, "NTaG213: Password + PACK");

            byte[] BufTmp = new byte[16];
            BufTmp = nfca.transceive(new byte[]{(byte) 0x1B,pwd_NTAG213[0],pwd_NTAG213[1], pwd_NTAG213[2], pwd_NTAG213[3]}); /* <----Error here */


            if (!Arrays.equals(BufTmp, pack_NTAG213)) {
                txtMsg.setText("No read NTAG213");
                toast.show();
                return;
            }
            //..................................................................................Lectura del NTAG213
            Log.i(TAG, "NTaG213: Read NTAG213");
            Buf[0] = nfca.transceive(new byte[]{(byte) 0x30, 28});
            Buf[1] = nfca.transceive(new byte[]{(byte) 0x30, 32});
            Buf[2] = nfca.transceive(new byte[]{(byte) 0x30, 36});

            txtMsg.setText("Read OK!!!");
            toast.show();
            return;


        } catch (IOException Failure) {
            Failure.printStackTrace();
            txtMsg.setText("Read Error!!!");
            toast.show();
            return;
        }
   }
}
```

I tested with another devices. They read OK NTAG213 tag

Samsung Galaxy A5
Android v.5.0.2
SM-A500FU

LG-D722v
Android v.4.4.2

Comment: "I have an exception" is not something we can help with unless your provide, at the bare minimum, 1) the exception and stacktrace and 2) the code generating the exception

Comment: I've updated the question with more information. I hope it's enough